# How to convince Apple definitively that I don't want to install iCloud?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, icloud

I run iTunes (v. 12.x) and keep getting an annoying pop-up asking me to install iCloud.

[image: Install the iCloud Control Panel?]

There's no option to say "no" definitively. Is there a way to get this to stop without uninstalling iTunes and/or the Apple software updater? (This is almost as annoying as the default install option for Safari that Apple has done in the past, as well as not having an installer option not to put a shortcut on my desktop).

EDIT: I determined that the dialog box belongs to iTunes. That is, you can't switch to iTunes without this dialog box blinking (and beeping).

Comment: iTunes has an Advanced preference to "Check for new software updates automatically" which is enabled. I have tried disabling it to see what happens...

Comment: Did you ever find a way to disable this nag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you click on "**Remind me later**" two times, it will change to "**No thanks**" on the third prompt:

[image: [Screenshot of the "No thanks" button]]
<sup><sub>([Screenshot source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150830135145/http://paulcunningham.me/stop-install-icloud-control-panel-prompt/))</sub></sup>

You won't get "No thanks" if you always click on the `[X]` to dismiss the dialog box.

The prompt won't happen again after clicking "No thanks".

Unfortunately, I was unable to determine where in the filesystem or registry iTunes stores the setting to display the popup for installing iCloud.

Comment: A screen shot of the "No thanks" button would be great.

Comment: Very similar answer to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5020074?tstart=0

Comment: Screen shot is here : http://paulcunningham.me/stop-install-icloud-control-panel-prompt/ -- accepting this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Go to start/Programs/Apple Software Update and check for updates...  It will (of course) offer you iCloud for Windows again. Check it off, then go up top of the window to "Tools" and select "Ignore Selected Update(s)"...
Done.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Software Update > Edit > Preferences.

Set update frequency to Never.

Comment: OK, I realize I wrote "without uninstalling updater" but your answer practically does the same, no? That is, I want to keep getting updates (reminders to update) iTunes.

Comment: iTunes itself will check on launch.

Comment: What about QuickTime (or is it also checked by iTunes on launch)?

Comment: idk on QT, I never use it so I've never checked. I doubt it's as interactive. I have to admit, Apple's updater for Windows is really irritating [I have several win machines here on which I just periodically have to quit the 'in your face' Apple updater, whilst swearing] - on the Mac it's seamless. In its defence, it's no more irritating than the Adobe or various anti-virus prompts.

Comment: QuickTime has to be installed for iTunes to work on Windows, if I'm not mistaken. So, disabling the updater would not be a good solution.

Comment: OK, different tack… if you update QT & iTunes every time prompted, do you still get periodic reminders to install iCloud, with no other updates needed, or only as an option when other elements need an update?

Comment: I think I get the "spam" install request when I start iTunes, but I'm not entirely sure of when it happens.

Comment: All I can say right now is, give it a day or so, see if someone can find something in the reg to stop it. I've never actually tried, I just click 'go away' & swear.